# How do you extract rows that contains specific string?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to extract all rows, that contains a specific string from an imported dataset, that has 5 columns. If a row had the specific string it would be in the 2 column.

monkeypox = Import["/Users/unknowen/Desktop/ProMat/Eksamen Jan 
2023/monkeypox.csv", "Dataset"]

The Data --->

```
monkeypox = {{"DateRep", "CountryExp", "CountryCode", "Source",
"ConfCases"}, {"2022-04-22", "Austria", "AT", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "Belgium", "BE", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22",
"Bulgaria", "BG", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Croatia", "HR",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Cyprus", "CY", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "Czechia", "CZ", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22",
"Denmark", "DK", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Estonia", "EE",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Finland", "FI", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "France", "FR", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22",
"Germany", "DE", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Greece", "EL",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Hungary", "HU", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "Iceland", "IS", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22",
"Ireland", "IE", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Italy", "IT", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "Latvia", "LV", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22",
"Lithuania", "LT", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Luxembourg", "LU",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Malta", "MT", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "Netherlands", "NL", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22",
"Norway", "NO", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Poland", "PL", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "Portugal", "PT", "TESSy", 1}, {"2022-04-22",
"Romania", "RO", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Slovakia", "SK",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22", "Slovenia", "SI", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-22", "Spain", "ES", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-22",
"Sweden", "SE", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29", "Austria", "AT",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29", "Belgium", "BE", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-29", "Bulgaria", "BG", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29",
"Croatia", "HR", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29", "Cyprus", "CY",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29", "Czechia", "CZ", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-29", "Denmark", "DK", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29",
"Estonia", "EE", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29", "Finland", "FI",
"TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29", "France", "FR", "TESSy",
0}, {"2022-04-29", "Germany", "DE", "TESSy", 0}, {"2022-04-29",
"Greece", "EL", "TESSy", 0} }
```

THE SPECIFIC STRING IS "Germany"

[image]

This is what I have tried to do but I have no idea how to do it with string values.

monkeypox[All, "Germany"]

This code gives me nothing btw.

Comment: Can you make a copy of your Excel file and delete all but a couple of lines of that, one containing Germany and one not, in Excel and save that Excel file and import that file into Mathematica and then paste into your post above the output of `FullForm[monkeypox]` That should show us and you what the real content of those couple of lines are. From that maybe someone will be able to spot what the problem is.

Comment: I edited a bit of the data above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your data. That showed nothing was hiding in the presentation.

Try

```
Cases[monkeypox,{_,"Germany",_,_,_}]
```

or

```
Select[monkeypox,#[[2]]=="Germany"&]
```

Either of those return

```
{{2022-04-22,Germany,DE,TESSy,0},{2022-04-29,Germany,DE,TESSy,0}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as smooth as butter <3. Btw, do you know of any websites that provide practice and learning around this kinda thing?? Like practice problems?

Comment: `https://www.google.com/search?q=learning+mathematica` will find lots of resources for you. Other similar queries will provide more. There are introductory books and online videos and classes and other resources to help you get started.

Comment: Helpful note to remember. There are always at least a dozen different ways of doing anything in Mathematica and almost always one or two of those are almost completely incomprehensible. Try to learn a handful of general ways of doing things that you will be able to use again and again and again, and be able to use those without making too many little mistakes. Each new major version of Mathematica will introduce hundreds of new functions. If you have your core set of methods that you can use without error then that will help you get your work done. Click on the orange Details&Options in help.